# StatefulSet recreates pod, why?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, kubernetes-statefulset

I have my deployment, where I have defined postgres statefulSet, however I have it without PVC so if pod is dead - all data is gone. If I will list all pods I see below picture:

```
pod1 - Running - 10 min
pod2 - Running - 10 min
postgresPod - Running - 10 min
```

After some time I list pods again and see below:

```
pod1 - Running - 10 min
pod2 - Running - 10 min
postgresPod - Running - 5 min
```

As you can see postgresPod running 5 min. I "described" statefulset and see there below:

```
Type     Reason               Age                From                    Message
  ----     ------               ----               ----                    -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate     5m **(x2 over 10m)**  statefulset-controller  create Pod postgresPod in StatefulSet x-postgres successful
  Warning  RecreatingFailedPod  5m                statefulset-controller  StatefulSet xx/x-postgres is recreating failed Pod postgresPod
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete     5m                statefulset-controller  **delete Pod postgresPod** in StatefulSet x-postgres successful
```

So my question is how I can know **why** statefulSet recreates the pods? Is there any additional log? Might be it is somehow related to resources of the machines, or pod was created on another node that has more resources on that specific moment?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into two things:

1. [Debug Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#debugging-pods)

> Check the current state of the pod and recent events with the
>   following command:
>
> `kubectl describe pods ${POD_NAME}` Look at the state of the containers
>   in the pod. Are they all Running? Have there been recent restarts?
>
> Continue debugging depending on the state of the pods.

Especially take a closer look at [why the Pod crashed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#my-pod-is-crashing-or-otherwise-unhealthy).

More info can be found in the links I have provided.

2. Debug StatefulSets.

StatefulSets provide a debug mechanism to pause all controller operations on Pods using an annotation. Setting the `pod.alpha.kubernetes.io/initialized` annotation to "false" on any StatefulSet Pod will pause all operations of the StatefulSet. When paused, the StatefulSet will not perform any scaling operations. Once the debug hook is set, you can execute commands within the containers of StatefulSet pods without interference from scaling operations. You can set the annotation to "false" by executing the following:

`kubectl annotate pods <pod-name> pod.alpha.kubernetes.io/initialized="false" --overwrite`

When the annotation is set to "false", the StatefulSet will not respond to its Pods becoming unhealthy or unavailable. It will not create replacement Pods till the annotation is removed or set to "true" on each StatefulSet Pod.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem as OP, stateful set gets the event and I can see the pod was recreated because it fails.  Old pods are deleted and the new pods just look new, no restarts, no problems.  Not sure how to find out how it failed.  K8s didn't seem to care when I annotated the pods, they just did the same thing.  This is k8s v1.14

Comment: I see that pod was re-created because previous one was in state failed. Question whether my pod failed because of lack of resources or for some other reason. And I don't know how I could understand it, because there is no logs of failed pod...

Comment: This annotation/feature has been deprecated since v.1.8

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/86f3fa94f1b75da275a8040e4155840a7b473dc1/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.8.md?plain=1#L1494

Answer (score 6):

Another nifty little trick I came up with is to `describe` the pod as soon as it stops logging, by using

```
kubectl logs -f mypod && kubectl describe pod mypod
```

When the pod fails and stops logging, the `kubectl logs -f mypod` will terminate and then the shell will immediately execute `kubectl describe pod mypod`, (hopefully) letting you catch the state of the failing pod before it is recreated.

In my case it was showing

```
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    137
```

in line with what Timothy is saying

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl log -p postgresPod` the `-p` will give you the previous logs (if it's a simple restart).

There's a whole bunch of "know the rest of your environment" that beg to be asked here. Do you know how many nodes make up your cluster (are we talking 1 or two or are we talking 10's 100's or more). Do you know if they are dedicated instances or are you on a cloud provider like AWS using spot instances.

Take a look at `kubectl get nodes` it will it should give you the age of your nodes.

Do you have requests and limits set on your pod? Do a `kubectl describe ${POD_NAME}`. Among the requests, limits etc you'll see which node the pod is on. Describe the node it will have CPU and memory details. Can your pod live within those.  Is your app configured to live within those limits ? If you don't have limits set then your pod could easily consume so many resources that the kernel oom killer terminates your pod.  If you do have pod limits, but have misconfigured your app then K8s may be killing your app because it is breaching the limits

If you have access to the node then take a look at `dmesg` to see if `OOM-Killer` has terminated any of your pods. If you don't have access get someone who does to take a look at the logs. When you're describing the node look for pods with `0` limits as that is unlimited and they may be misbehaving and causing your app to be killed because it was unlucky enough to request more resource from the system when there was non available due to unlimited apps.